# Get value from firebase and render it to render function in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why this code is not running when I replace `value` to `child_added`? How can I solve it?

If it's possibile to get values on `child-added` with another way out of this function to render, please share

```
var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('messages');
messagesRef.off();

messagesRef.limitToLast(12).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    var Text = [];
    snapshot.forEach((data) => {
        var text = {
            text: data.val().text
        }
        Text.push(text);
        this.setState({
            Text: Text
        });

    })


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

- `value` is only triggered once with a list of all your messages.
- `child_added` would be triggered for every single message you have under the reference. And every time a new child is added to parent reference.

Try the following code, assuming `messages` is a list of messages in your react state.

```
var messages = []
messagesRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    messages.push({
        text: snapshot.val().text
    })
    this.setState({ messages })
})
```